# What is debezium solution to show who and when deleted records logs?

Tags: spring, hibernate, audit, cd, debezium

I have *spring boot* + *hibernate* application and now i want to use debezium to capture date change.
Assume that this class is one of my POJO entity classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "app_user")
public class User {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String firstName;

    // getters and setters are omitted for brevity
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "app_article")
public class Article {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "category")
    private String category;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "created_by")
    private User createdBy;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "updated_by")
    private User updatedBy;

    @Column(name = "created_date")
    private Date createdDate;

    @Column(name = "updated_date")
    private Date updatedDate;

    // getters and setters are omitted for brevity
}
```

Now, if i create new `Article` object and persists it with code something like this:

```
Article article = new Article();

article.setId(1);
article.setTitle("Introduction to Debezium");
article.setCategory("auditing");
article.setCreatedBy(Utils.getCurrentUser());
article.setUpdatedBy(Utils.getCurrentUser());
article.setCreatedDate(new Date());
article.setUpdatedDate(new Date());

entityManager.persist(article);
```

Then load it again and change some fields and persist it:

```
Article art = entityManager.load(Article.class, 1);

art.setTitle("Introduction to Debezium for beginners");
art.setCategory("auditing and cdc");
art.setCreatedBy(Utils.getCurrentUser());
art.setUpdatedBy(Utils.getCurrentUser());
art.setCreatedDate(new Date());
art.setUpdatedDate(new Date());

entityManager.persist(art);
```

and then delete it:

```
entityManager.delete(Article.class, 1);
```

I may be see logs like these in each step:

```
// create
{
    "payload" : {
        "before" : null,
        "after" : {
            "id" : 1,
            "title" : "Introduction to Debezium",
            "category" : "auditing",
            "created_by" : 1,
            "updated_by" : 1,
            "created_date" : "11/29/2017",
            "updated_date" : "11/29/2017"
        },
        "source" : {
            "name" : "dbserver1",
            "server_id" : 223344,
            "ts_sec" : 1500369632,
            "gtid" : null,
            "file" : "mysql-bin.000003",
            "pos" : 364,
            "row" : 0,
            "snapshot" : null,
            "thread" : 13,
            "db" : "app",
            "table" : "app_article"
        },
        "op" : "c",
        "ts_ms" : 1500369632095
    }
}

// update
{
    "payload" : {
        "before" : {
            "id" : 1,
            "title" : "Introduction to Debezium",
            "category" : "auditing",
            "created_by" : 1,
            "updated_by" : 1,
            "created_date" : "11/29/2017",
            "updated_date" : "11/29/2017"
        }
        "after" : {
            "id" : 1,
            "title" : "Introduction to Debezium for beginners",
            "category" : "auditing and cdc",
            "created_by" : 1,
            "updated_by" : 1,
            "created_date" : "11/29/2017",
            "updated_date" : "11/29/2017"
        },
        "source" : {
            "name" : "dbserver1",
            "server_id" : 223344,
            "ts_sec" : 1500369632,
            "gtid" : null,
            "file" : "mysql-bin.000003",
            "pos" : 364,
            "row" : 0,
            "snapshot" : null,
            "thread" : 13,
            "db" : "app",
            "table" : "app_article"
        },
        "op" : "u",
        "ts_ms" : 1500369632095
    }
}

// delete
{
    "payload" : {
        "before" : {
            "id" : 1,
            "title" : "Introduction to Debezium for beginners",
            "category" : "auditing and cdc",
            "created_by" : 1,
            "updated_by" : 1,
            "created_date" : "11/29/2017",
            "updated_date" : "11/29/2017"
        },
        "after": null,
        "source" : {
            "name" : "dbserver1",
            "server_id" : 223344,
            "ts_sec" : 1500369632,
            "gtid" : null,
            "file" : "mysql-bin.000003",
            "pos" : 364,
            "row" : 0,
            "snapshot" : null,
            "thread" : 13,
            "db" : "app",
            "table" : "app_article"
        },
        "op" : "d",
        "ts_ms" : 1500369632095
    }
}
```

As you can see above, i can not detect how deleted a record from database. how can i solve this problem? should i use something like **Hibernate Enver**
to supplementary this?

Answer (score 2):

You could work with *logical* deletes, which don't actually remove the `Article` records from your table, but just set a `deleted` flag. That way the user will be part of the transmitted update event.

You could then implement some kind of (asynchronously running) housekeeping which physically removes the records. The (technical) user performing this deletion wouldn't be of much interest of the resulting delete events.